# Get location while app is closed

Tags: android, bluetooth, location, broadcastreceiver

I am stucked right now with my task i need to perform.

Small description what i have, and what i need. I have an app, that has google map, and i can save my location on it. I can save my location to a file and shared preferences.

I have a **Broadcast receiver**, that is called, when i disconnect from bluetooth. It works fine, even if i remove app from recents. My task is, to save my location (when accuracy is <=20m) to the file or shared preferences when device disconnects even if the app is closed. I tried implementing **LocationListener** in the receiver, but app is crashing in background when i call it.

Is it even possible?...

Maybe i need a service, but i never worked with one before. So i need some help, examples, tutorials, everything that could help me. I tried to search on my own, but there is nothing that matches my purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed correctly,  what you need is a service.

"A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed."

More information at [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

It also includes Code examples...